# Pop-up interference in Elementor plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, popup, elementor, popupmenu

I had a question. I have created a pop-up menu for my site by Elementor pop-up, and every time I click on the icon in header of site, the menu opens from the right and there is no problem. And I also created a pop-up back-to-top for the site and that is no problem. But once I open and close the menu pop-up, the pop-up back-to-top is no longer displayed. What do you think is the problem? How do I configure pop-up settings?

Answer (score 0):

Check and set conditions of popup back-to-top